# uiwebview display html really small...?

Tags: iphone, html, uiwebview

I'm using uiwebview in my iPhone app.
where I'm bind it with local html file,but it not display me proper.
my html file code

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        h1 {font-family:arabic-indic;font-size:14px;font-weight:bold}       </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table align="center" border="0" width="100%">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1>
                        First Name</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h1>
                        9898337874</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1>
                        Last Name</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <h1>
                        mjain@jkvsolutions.com</h1>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <h1>
                        Image</h1>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <img alt="" src="http://wac.450f.edgecastcdn.net/80450F/929jackfm.com/files/2013/01/some-ecards-2.jpg" style="width: 90px; height: 90px; " /></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
```

it display proper in locla browser when I open same file in local pc browser.
but with iphone uiwebview
[image]

code using which I'm load it in app

```
    [tblwebview loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle]
                                                                      pathForResource:@"htmlfile" ofType:@"htm"]isDirectory:NO]]];
for (id subview in tblwebview.subviews)
    if ([[subview class] isSubclassOfClass: [UIScrollView class]])
        ((UIScrollView *)subview).bounces = NO;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Uncheck property "Scales Page To Fit" if you have it set, and try again. It helped me a lot with my work, however, I did have to spend a lot of time perfecting the "killer" CSS to display the stuff exactly as I needed.

Comment: I didn't realize this post was 1 year old :/

Answer (score 0):

add following meta tag in header.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">
```